# An application of derivatives problem- to show that $f(x+2)-f(x)>2$ for $f(x)=x\cos(1/x)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, inequality

I have this function $$f(x) = x\cos(1/x)$$ defined for all $x \geq 1$.

> How do I prove that 
>   $$f(x+2)-f(x)>2$$ 
>   for all $x\geq 1$?

I found $$f'(x)= \cos(1/x) + \frac{\sin(1/x)}{x}$$
and $$f''(x)=-\frac{\cos(1/x)}{x^3}.$$ How do i use this information?

Comment: Please format your equations with [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Consider the function $g(x)=f(x+2)-f(x)-2$ and show that it is decreasing over the given domain and $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=0$.

Comment: That's also a good idea: $g'(x) = f'(x+2) - f'(x)$ and as $f'(x)$ is a decreasing function, $g'(x) < 0$ , but I'm not sure how to prove $lim_{x→∞}g(x)=0$ , as $x→∞$, $f(x)→∞$ and $f(x+2)→∞$ so how would we find this.

Comment: @Jam, thanks now i know how to use Mathjax :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f''(x) <0$ so $f'(x)$ is decreasing. 
min value of $f'(x)$ occurs at $\infty$, which is $1$.
now apply LMVT on $[x,x+2]$,
$f'(c) = \frac{f(x+2)-f(x)}{x+2-x}$ 
but $f'(c) > 1$,  for $x> 1$ hence proved