# Solution using $f\left( x \right) = x\cos \frac{1}{x},x \ge 1$

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

If $f\left( x \right) = x\cos \frac{1}{x},x \ge 1$.
Then which of the following is the correct option for the domain $x \ge 1$

(A) $f(x+2)-f(x)<2$

(B) $f(x+2)-f(x)>2$

My approach is as follow

$T\left( x \right) = f\left( {x + 2} \right) - f\left( x \right) = \left( {x + 2} \right)\cos \frac{1}{{x + 2}} - x\cos \frac{1}{x}$

$T\left( x \right) = x\left( {\cos \frac{1}{{x + 2}} - \cos \frac{1}{x}} \right) + 2\cos \frac{1}{{x + 2}} \Rightarrow T\left( x \right) = x\left( {2\sin \left( {\frac{{\frac{1}{{x + 2}} + \frac{1}{x}}}{2}} \right)\sin \left( {\frac{{\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{{x + 2}}}}{2}} \right)} \right) + 2\cos \frac{1}{{x + 2}}$

$T\left( x \right) = x\left( {2\sin \left( {\frac{{2x + 2}}{{2x\left( {x + 2} \right)}}} \right)\sin \left( {\frac{2}{{2x\left( {x + 2} \right)}}} \right)} \right) + 2\cos \frac{1}{{x + 2}} \Rightarrow T\left( x \right) = x\left( {2\sin \left( {\frac{{x + 1}}{{x\left( {x + 2} \right)}}} \right)\sin \left( {\frac{1}{{x\left( {x + 2} \right)}}} \right)} \right) + 2\cos \frac{1}{{x + 2}}$

$T\left( x \right) = 2\left( {\left( x{\sin \left( {\frac{{x + 1}}{{x\left( {x + 2} \right)}}} \right)\sin \left( {\frac{1}{{x\left( {x + 2} \right)}}} \right)} \right) + \cos \frac{1}{{x + 2}}} \right)$

From here onward how do I proceed

Comment: Did you calculate $f(3)-f(1)$?

Comment: no, my first plan is to use T(x) and then proceed

Comment: You're given two options and you can choose between them by calculating $f(3)-f(1)$. I expect you're doing a lot more work than was intended.

Comment: f(x) is a increasing function so if f(3)-f(1)>2, then it will be satisfied but want to generalize it

Comment: Try using the Mean Value theorem $(f(x+2) - f(x) )/2  = f'(c), f'(c) =  \cos(1/c) + 1/c \sin(1/c)$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An application of derivatives problem- to show that $f(x+2)-f(x) >2$ for $f(x)=x\cos(1/x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2909949/an-application-of-derivatives-problem-to-show-that-fx2-fx2-for-fx-x)

Answer (score 0):

From your expression $T(x)$, now we find roots for

$$
T(x) - 2 = 0 \\
x \sin\left( \frac{x+1}{x(x+2)} \right) \sin\left( \frac{1}{x(x+2)} \right) + \cos \left(\frac{1}{x+2}\right) - 1 = 0
$$

Comparing denominators and numerators inside every sin and cos expresion:

$$
x+1 < x(x+2)\\
1 < x(x+2)\\
1 < x+2
$$

So *sin* and *cos* expresions are monotonic. Check that:

$$
x \sin\left( \frac{x+1}{x(x+2)} \right) \sin\left( \frac{1}{x(x+2)} \right) \to 0  \text{ 
 (monotonically increassing)}\\
\cos \left(\frac{1}{x+2}\right) \to 1  \text{ 
 (monotonically decreasing)}
$$

Then note that

$$
1 \sin\left( \frac{1+1}{1(1+2)} \right) \sin\left( \frac{1}{1(1+2)} \right) = 0.20232\dots \\
\cos \left(\frac{1}{1+2}\right) = 0.94495\dots 
$$

Also
$$
T(1) - 2 = 0.20232 + 0.94495 - 1 = 0.14727 > 0\\
T(x) - 2 \to 0 \text{(monotonically)}
$$

Thus

$T(x) > 2$

Not that rigorous but hope it helps,
Bests!